# html email sent to facebook address has style broken

Tags: html, facebook, email

I wrote a php script to send a message, with html formatting and custom css styles,
to a facebook user. The message can be seen in his private message box.
it would be perfect if html formatting was kept on.
The only way I found to do that was to put the style inline (as a tag attribute)
instead of writing an internal style section or using an external css file.

ex: <div style="width:100px">

But I have two problems.
image in img tag does not display and I cannot insert a wrapper block to fit the whole message width.

How can I do that properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what quirks facebook has, but it is best practice to include inline styling and also using tables in html email. For your image to work, it probably needs to be hosted online, not embedded.

Assuming facebook doesn't strip any code out, a simple table like this should fit the width:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:20px; padding-bottom:0;">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" width="400" height="200" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000; padding:20px;">
      Content here.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note - this is not a full html email structure, just a table that should be placed inside your body section.